# RStudio continues to crash when I use the "spread" function from the tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyr

I'm trying to spread a dataframe, but R continues to crash everytime I try. I can use other functions from the tidyverse, like mutate, filter, etc, but I'm unable to use spread. When I try to cancel the code, a Terminate R dialog box pops up explaining that R is not responding to my request to interrupt the current operation and that I should terminate R.

I've tried uninstalling and then reinstalling tidyr and tidyverse, but no luck.

Does anyone have an idea as to why this might be happening or a possible solution to the problem?

Comment: What are the dimensions of your initial and expected dataframes ?

Comment: That doesn't sound like it crashes R, just that it's taking a long time and won't let you stop the processing, right? You could try using `data.table::dcast` instead, since that function is more efficient. You'd have to convert your data to a data.table with `data.table::setDT(data_name)` though.

Comment: The initial dataframe is only 93,364 by 7, and I expect it to be 4,624 by 26.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan, it doesn't seem like it should take that long though. A colleague of mine just tried the same code in her RStudio and it returned the expected results almost immediately, and our computers are exactly the same.

Comment: I will try that, though it will have to wait till later today or tomorrow. I'm under deadline and for the time being I can just use the data my colleague manage to create.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem once. I noticed it occurs after use group_by and summarize. dplyr converts the new dataset class to *"grouped_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"* and for some reason that I don't know *spread* does not work properly.

If that is your case, just force the class to be data.frame with the *as.data.frame (dataset)* command before submitting your dataset to the spread function.

It worked for me!